# How to remove titlebar when maximising youtube videos in awesome 3.5?

Tags: youtube, fullscreen, titlebar, awesome-wm

Since I migrated from awesome 3.4 to 3.5 I am unable to remove titlebar from youtube videos when maximising fullscreen.

In awesome 3.4 I used to put:

```
{ rule = { instance = "plugin-container" },
        properties = { floating = true } },
```

and that works. However in version 3.5 the titlebar "plugin-container" remains. I even tried the following without much success:

```
{ rule = { instance = "plugin-container" },
properties = { floating = true }  , 
callback = function (c) awful.titlebar(c, {size = 0}) end },
```

However the function works when I hooked it to a keybinding:

```
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "w",  
function (c) awful.titlebar(c, {size = 0}) end
```

I know for sure that the rule works because it makes the window floating but does not execute the call to the function, so I am really perplexed to what is the issue here.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem, here's a config section which does the wanted behavior:

```
{ rule = { instance = "plugin-container" },
  properties = { floating = true },
  callback = awful.titlebar.hide },
```

May be a little bit late, but I think it's worth documenting.